# Broken css code - border doesnt get overwritten

Tags: css, css-selectors, border

So i have encountered a new problem which was never the case before.

```
<ul id="mainmenu">
    <li class="mbutton"><a class="currentnav" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="mbutton"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="mbutton"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

.mbutton a {
    font-family:"Archivo Narrow",Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 3px;
    padding:11px 20px 9px 20px;
    color:#404040;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.mbutton a:hover {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.currentnav {
    border: 1px solid #e82c3d;
}
```

To my surprise the `.currentnav` is not overwriting the border that was set by `.mbutton a`!

I never had this problem before so im thinking this way always worked. Can anyone tell me how to make it work please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style with greater specificity takes precedence.

Since the first style is declared as `.mbutton a`, you need `.mbutton .currentnav` to override it.

Comment: I didnt knew that. Thank you for answer! I also tried adding .currentnav to <li class="mbutton currentnav"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li> but it also didn't worked. So now i will definately remember how to write that in css!

Answer (score 1):

```
.mbutton .currentnav {
     border: 1px solid #e82c3d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your override is not applied because `.currentNav` is a less specific selector than `.mbutton a`.

Please refer to [W3's docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#specificity) :

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - negative selectors are counted like their simple selectors argument
> - count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= a)
> - count the number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the    selector (= b)
> - count the number of element names in the selector (= c)
> - ignore pseudo-elements.
>
> Concatenating the three numbers a-b-c (in a number system with a large
>   base) gives the specificity.

### Example

Some examples:

```
*               /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> specificity =   0 */
LI              /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> specificity =   1 */
UL LI           /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> specificity =   2 */
UL OL+LI        /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> specificity =   3 */
H1 + *[REL=up]  /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> specificity =  11 */
UL OL LI.red    /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> specificity =  13 */
LI.red.level    /* a=0 b=2 c=1 -> specificity =  21 */
#x34y           /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> specificity = 100 */
#s12:not(FOO)   /* a=1 b=0 c=1 -> specificity = 101 */
```

Another [cool reference](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) that will help (if you're a starwars fan).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.currentnav {
    border: 1px solid #e82c3d;
}
```

to

```
.mbutton .currentnav {
    border: 1px solid #e82c3d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go... http://jsfiddle.net/gcvbJ/

The answer is to add .mbutton to the .currentnav declaration, thus:

```
.mbutton .currentnav {
    border: 1px solid #e82c3d;
}
```